# componentDidCatch throws cross-origin error

Tags: reactjs, cross-origin-read-blocking, react-error-boundary

I have a react app with the following structure:

```
<ErroBoundary>
    <Component/>
</ErroBoundary>
```

Inside Component render function I throw the exception:

```
render(): React.ReactNode {
    throw new Error('error message');
}
```

In the ErrorBoundary I have the following code:

```
componentDidCatch(error: any, info: any) {
    alert("Action failed " + error)
}
```

When I run this app in the browser, I get the following error:

```
Action failed Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.
```

I've tried to replace

```
throw new Error('error message');
```

with

```
throw 'error message'
```

but I'm still getting the same error. I'm running react app on the remote server, and I'm connecting to it by my computer remotely. Can you help me to figure out what might be a reason here?